# How do I get a list of all the printable characters in C#?

Tags: c#

I'd like to be able to get a char array of all the printable characters in C#, does anybody know how to do this?

**edit:**

By printable I mean the visible European characters, so yes, umlauts, tildes, accents etc.

Comment: Please define "printable" - do you mean just "printable ASCII characters" (as per ilivewithin's answer) or would you want to include accented characters?

Comment: I'm assuming by print we're talking about printable on paper? If you're looking for just an ascii lookup http://www.asciitable.com is one. For unicode charmap.exe is the obvious option.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This will give you a list with all characters that are not considered control characters:

```
List<Char> printableChars = new List<char>();
for (int i = char.MinValue; i <= char.MaxValue; i++)
{
    char c = Convert.ToChar(i);
    if (!char.IsControl(c))
    {
        printableChars.Add(c);
    }
}
```

You may want to investigate the other [Char.IsXxxx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char_members.aspx) methods to find a combination that suits your requirements.

Comment: For a reason I don't understand, if you do: for (char c = char.MinValue; c <= char.MaxValue; c++) OutOfMemoryException - the list fills up fast

Comment: It looks like the c++ statement makes the counter wrap to 0 after 65535, meaning that c <= char.MaxValue will always be true. The int can hold larger values, so it increments beyound char.MaxValue, and the exit condition is fulfilled and the loop stops.

Comment: (I sometimes wish comments could be edited so those annoying spelling errors could be removed...)

Answer (score 23):

Here's a LINQ version of Fredrik's solution. Note that `Enumerable.Range` yields an `IEnumerable<int>` so you have to convert to chars first. `Cast<char>` would have worked in 3.5SP0 I believe, but as of 3.5SP1 you have to do a "proper" conversion:

```
var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, char.MaxValue+1)
                      .Select(i => (char) i)
                      .Where(c => !char.IsControl(c))
                      .ToArray();
```

I've created the result as an array as that's what the question asked for - it's not necessarily the best idea though. It depends on the use case.

Note that this also doesn't consider full Unicode characters, only those in the basic multilingual plane. I don't know what it returns for high/low surrogates, but it's worth at least knowing that a single `char` doesn't really let you represent everything :(

Comment: I really need to dive into that Linq stuff, there are some elegant solutions to find there :o)

Comment: Darn, so I beat Jon Skeet to it and my answer still loses out. :( Just as a note: You could replace that Select call with a Cast to make it marginally nicer.

Comment: Downvoters, please give reasons. (Note that although this is similar to Noldorin's answer, I believe it gives more information - and it works :)

Comment: Noldorin: You posted faster because it took me a minute to test that my code worked :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Well, would have still been faster if I had taken the minute, but meh. I guess collaboration on this site really is out of the window if there are votes up for grabs. :P

Comment: @Noldorin: If I hadn't been half way through writing my post when yours came up, I'd probably have just commented on it. As it is, I felt that my post was clearer (in terms of formatting), worked from the start, and included extra useful information... so I didn't see much point in abandoning it at that stage.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yeah, so that's fair enough. You have indeed provided more (helpful) info than me.

Answer (score 4):

A LINQ solution (based on Fredrik Mörk's):

```
Enumerable.Range(char.MinValue, char.MaxValue).Select(c => (char)c).Where(
    c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Whoops, need the cast there. Cheers.

Comment: ...but then again I realize I don't run SP1.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Not sure why the designers made that change in SP1...would seem logical to allow the cast from int to char.

Comment: There's a blog post by Eric Lippert about this, but I can't find it at the moment. Basically it was never meant to support this sort of conversion. I agree it's slightly odd and annoying though.

Comment: The 2nd argument to Range is a count... doesn't that mean it should be `char.MaxValue - char.MinValue`?

Answer (score 1):

#### TLDR Answer

Use this Regex...

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[^\p{Cc}^\p{Cn}^\p{Cs}]");
```

#### TLDR Explanation

- `^\p{Cc}` : *Do not* match control characters.
- `^\p{Cn}` : *Do not* match unassigned characters.
- `^\p{Cs}` : *Do not* match UTF-8-invalid characters.

#### Working Demo

I test two strings in this demo: `"Hello, World!"` and `"Hello, World!" + (char)4`.  `char(4)` is the character for [`END TRANSMISSION`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0004/index.htm).

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test {
    public static MatchCollection getPrintableChars(string haystack) {
        var regex = new Regex(@"[^\p{Cc}^\p{Cn}^\p{Cs}]");
        var matches = regex.Matches(haystack);
        return matches;
    }
    public static void Main() {
        var teststring1 = "Hello, World!";
        var teststring2 = "Hello, World!" + (char)4;
        
        var teststring1unprintablechars = getPrintableChars(teststring1);
        var teststring2unprintablechars = getPrintableChars(teststring2);
        
        Console.WriteLine("Testing a Printable String: " + teststring1unprintablechars.Count + " Printable Chars Detected");
        Console.WriteLine("Testing a String With 1-Unprintable Char: " + teststring2unprintablechars.Count + " Printable Chars Detected");
        
        foreach (Match unprintablechar in teststring1unprintablechars) {
            Console.WriteLine("String 1 Printable Char:" + unprintablechar);
        }
        
        foreach (Match unprintablechar in teststring2unprintablechars) {
            Console.WriteLine("String 2 Printable Char:" + unprintablechar);
        }
    }
}
```

[**Full Working Demo at IDEOne.com**](https://ideone.com/HF5KV4)

#### Alternatives

- `\P{C}` : Match only visible characters.  Do not match any invisible characters.
- `\P{Cc}` : Match only non-control characters.  Do not match any control characters.
- `\P{Cc}\P{Cn}` : Match only non-control characters that have been assigned.  Do not match any control or unassigned characters.
- `\P{Cc}\P{Cn}\P{Cs}` :  Match only non-control characters that have been assigned and are UTF-8 valid.  Do not match any control, unassigned, or UTF-8-invalid characters.
- `\P{Cc}\P{Cn}\P{Cs}\P{Cf}` :  Match only non-control, non-formatting characters that have been assigned and are UTF-8 valid.  Do not match any control, unassigned, formatting, or UTF-8-invalid characters.

#### Source and Explanation

Take a look at the [Unicode Character Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) available that can be used to test within a regex.  You should be able to use these regexes in [Microsoft .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions), [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes), [Python](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), [Java](https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode), [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/parle.regex.unicodecharclass.php), [Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html), [Perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlrecharclass), [Golang](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/), and even [Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-regular-expressions-in-functions/regular-expression-syntax.html).  Knowing Unicode character classes is *very transferable knowledge*, so I recommend using it!

Answer (score 0):

I know ASCII wasn't specifically requested but this is a quick way to get a list of all the printable ASCII characters.

```
for (Int32 i = 0x20; i <= 0x7e; i++)
{
    printableChars.Add(Convert.ToChar(i));
}
```

See this [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Edit:

As stated by Péter Szilvási, the `0x20` and `0x7e` in the loop are hexidecimal representations of the base 10 numbers `32` and `126`, which are the printable ASCII characters.

Comment: An alternative for loop could be: `for (int i = 32; i <= 126; i++)`. In this case the decimal code is used for defining the character. The printable character decimal code is between 32 and 126.

Answer (score -1):

```
public bool IsPrintableASCII(char c)
{
     return c >= '\x20' && c <= '\x7e';
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue