# Check if Keys is Letter/Digit/Special Symbol

Tags: c#, key

I override `ProcessCmdKey` and when I get `Keys` argument, I want to check if this `Keys` is Letter or Digit or Special Symbol.

I have this snippet

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
            char key = (char)keyData;
            if(char.IsLetterOrDigit(key)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(key);
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

Everything works for letters and digits. but when I press F1-F12 it converts them to letters.

Maybe someone knows better way to solve this task?

Comment: The problem is you're casting `keyData` to a character. You can't do that. You have to use the constants defined in the `Keys` enumeration to get this information.

Comment: May be you could Try

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887377/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-printable-characters-in-c

Comment: Looking at the values of the `Keys` enum, one does indeed initially think "these enum values are character codes". But thinking about it further that is impossible, because a) there are keys which does not have characters, e.g. `Sleep`, and b) there are also keys that share the same character, e.g. `D0` and `NumPad0`: even though they have the same character `0`  they can't both share to the same enum value because then they would be indistinguishable, thus at least one of them maps to some arbitrary value.   (I know this is old, I just wanted to clarify _why_ casting doesn't work.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Override the form's `OnKeyPress` method instead. The `KeyPressEventArgs` provides a [`KeyChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.keychar.aspx) property which allows you to utilize the static methods on `char`.

As mentioned by Cody Gray in the comments, this method only fires on key strokes that have character information. Other key strokes such as F1-F12 should be processed in `OnKeyDown` or `OnKeyUp`, depending on your situation.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx):

> Key events occur in the following
>   order:
>
> - [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx)
> - [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx)
> - [KeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx)
>
> The **KeyPress event is not raised by
>   noncharacter keys**; however, the
>   noncharacter keys do raise the KeyDown
>   and KeyUp events.

**Example**

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnKeyPress(e);
  if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
  {
    // char is letter
  }
  else if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
  {
    // char is digit
  }
  else
  {
    // char is neither letter or digit.
    // there are more methods you can use to determine the
    // type of char, e.g. char.IsSymbol
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that this happens at a much higher level than the `ProcessCmdKey`, and it's subject to missing certain keypresses for various reasons. If it works for your purposes, great. But it's important to realize that it might not—it is not a drop-in replacement with equivalent functionality and purpose.

Comment: Definitely not, `OnKeyPress` only provides the `KeyChar` and nothing else, which is why it is so fitting for this specific situation. Other key strokes should be processed in `OnKeyDown`.

Comment: .. or `OnKeyUp` for that matter. I've updated the answer with more info.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if( !(keyData >= Keys.F1 && keyData <= Keys.F12))
{
    char key = (char)keyData;
    if(char.IsLetterOrDigit(key))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(key);
        return false;
    }

}
return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
```

Comment: I don't need to do something when F1-F12 pressed. I need to check if I pressed letter,digit or special symbol

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`keyData.KeyCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) and maybe even testing within a range instead of using the Char.IsLetterOrDigit. e.g.

```
if (keyData.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 && keyData.KeyCode <= Keys.Z) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: What about special symbols `+ = - / \ ? ` and e.t.c

Comment: @Zlobaton: You mean `Keys.Add`, `Keys.Subtract`, `Keys.Divide`, etc.?

Comment: And bang, all users of your software that use a non-Latin-based keyboard (e.g. Russian, Greek, Hindi, ...) experience completely broken software. There is a reason for the existence of `char.IsLetterOrDigit` et al. — use them.

Comment: I mean all symbols that you can type.

Comment: @Timwi: The point I was stressing was `KeyCode` exists (and not to start off with a cast). You're absolutely right, it would not be universal.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (keyData >= Keys.F1 && keyData <= Keys.F12)
{
     //one of the key between F1~F12 is pressed
}
```

Comment: I don't need to do something when F1-F12 pressed. I need to check if I pressed letter,digit or special symbol

Comment: @Zlobaton: Define *special symbol*.

Answer (score 0):

you need either a giant switch/case statement or check for ranges. You may find it easier to check for the keys you want to exclude, depending on which there is fewer of. Look at this for all the possible values. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx

```
if (keyData >= Keys.A && keyData <= Keys.Z)
   // do something
```

or

```
switch(keyData) {
case Keys.Add:
case Keys.Multiply:
// etc.
   // do something
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code but for some reason char.IsLetter() method is recognising the following keys as Letters???

F1, F8, F9, F11, F12, RightShift, LeftShift, RightAlt, RightCtrl, LeftCtrl, LeftWin, RightWin, NumLock.

This method doesn't seem to be that full proof regarding what it thinks is a letter.

```
if(char.IsLetter((char)e.Key) || char.IsDigit((char)e.Key))
```