# How to determine if a key is a letter or number?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, key

[`KeyboardState.GetPressedKeys()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keyboardstate.getpressedkeys.aspx) returns a `Key` array of currently pressed keys. Normally to find out if a key is a letter or number I would use [`Char.IsLetterOrDigit(char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cay4xx2f.aspx) but the given type is of the `Keys` enumeration and as a result has no `KeyChar` property.

Casting does not work either because, for example, keys like `Keys.F5`, when casted to a character, become the letter `t`. In this case, `F5` would then be seen as a letter or digit when clearly it is not.

So, how might one determine if a given `Keys` enumeration value is a letter or digit, given that casting to a character gives unpredictable results?

Comment: You wish F5 to be flagged as a letter or a number?

Comment: Look here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718541/check-if-keys-is-letter-digit-special-symbol

Comment: @SwearWord: No. The problem is that when `Keys.F5` is casted to a character it becomes `t`. `Keys.F5` should fail the *is letter or number* test.

Comment: [This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xnaframework/thread/d4ffe642-cf35-4ccd-92ab-0c0dfd17c95d/) from the MSDN XNA forums may be of help.

Comment: @RyanPeschel are you interested in letters that would be typed when key is pressed or always English letters that directly correspond to `Keys`? If former Kamil's link provides good approach.

Comment: A Key is a Key, and not a number or letter. There is no simple mapping between keys and characters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
public static bool IsKeyAChar(Keys key)
{
    return key >= Keys.A && key <= Keys.Z;
}

public static bool IsKeyADigit(Keys key)
{
    return (key >= Keys.D0 && key <= Keys.D9) || (key >= Keys.NumPad0 && key <= Keys.NumPad9);
}
```

Comment: Can't find it in Keys enumeration (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keys.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Given that “digit keys” correspond to specific ranges within the `Keys` enumeration, couldn’t you just check whether your key belongs to any of the ranges?

```
Keys[] keys = KeyboardState.GetPressedKeys();
bool isDigit = keys.Any(key =>
    key >= Keys.D0      && key <= Keys.D9 || 
    key >= Keys.NumPad0 && key <= Keys.NumPad9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your own table/set of HashSets to map `Keys` enumeration to types your are interested.

There are only about hundred different values - so table will not be too big. If you worried about size in memory - it is one byte per enumeration value (if using a byte array indexed by `Keys` values).