# How to detect if ANY keyboard Function key has been pressed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

I was wondering if there's a way to detect if any of the function keyboard keys were pressed in one statement rather than listing them all like so:

```
if( !(e.Key == Key.F1) && !(e.Key == Key.F2) && !(e.Key == Key.F3) ...... !(e.Key == Key.F12))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718541/check-if-keys-is-letter-digit-special-symbol

That should answer your question

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be:

```
var key = e.SystemKey == Key.None ? e.Key : e.SystemKey;
if(key >= Key.F1 && key <= Key.F12)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually necessarily detect F10

Comment: Can you safely assume that `Key.F1 < Key.F2 < Key.F3` etc. and that there are no gaps, i.e. `(int)Key.F1 == (int)Key.F2-1 == (int)Key.F3-2` etc.? Is this docmented somewhere?

Comment: @Alan: It sure does: `Assert.Equal(99, Key.F10);`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes, but press F10 you get value 156 !

Comment: @Clemens: Unfortunately, this is not documented. At least not on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.key%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: This is why I prefer the switch statement. It's clear and doesn't make assumptions on the values of the keys.

Comment: @Alan: Ha, indeed. Now that is very strange. I fixed my code to additionally use `KeyEventArgs.SystemKey`.

Comment: @Alan: I would also use a switch statement or similar and hide it away in an extension method. I might even go with the `if` of the OP. But he was asking for alternatives, presumably, because his current solution is "too long".

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Well, I think my If statement works then. It is shorter and has the OR for Key.System. I think it is somewhat reasonable to assume they won't be changing those key values. But it if it is life or death this always works, I may use the switch instead.

Comment: @RobHurd: Please see update. As Alan said, the F10 key was not properly detected.

Comment: @Alan: Your if statement works. But we don't actually know why F10 is translated to System and so we don't know if that is actually the case for every machine. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I see, yes that is good to notice I will update my answers to make this observation

Answer (score 2):

It seems the values for the F keys are all sequential
F1 = 90
F12 = 101

However usually F10 pressed results in the sorta unexpected,

156 (System)

So it might be tempting to do a range check like

```
Key actualKey = (e.SystemKey == Key.None) ? e.Key : e.SystemKey;
if(actualKey >= Key.F1 && actualKey <= Key.F12)
// F Key was pressed
```

And this is probably ok, to detect any F key. But I also like this solution using a switch:

```
Key actualKey = (e.SystemKey == Key.None) ? e.Key : e.SystemKey;
switch (actualKey)
        {
            case Key.F1:
            case Key.F2:
            case Key.F3:
            case Key.F4:
            case Key.F5:
            case Key.F6:
            case Key.F7:
            case Key.F8:
            case Key.F9:
            case Key.F10:
            case Key.F11:
            case Key.F12:
                // fkey
                break;

            default:
                // no fkey

                break;
        }
```

Comment: @DanielHilgarth It does, but that's not what is returned when you press it for some reason.