# Enumerate all possible characters

Tags: c#, .net, char

How can I enumerate all possible instances of System.Char ? I need to see for which ones System.Char.IsSymbol returns true, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq-y answer to give you the symbol characters:

```
var chars = Enumerable.Range(0, char.MaxValue+1)
                      .Select(i => (char) i)
                      .Where(c => char.IsSymbol(c))
                      .ToArray();
```

Credit really should go Sir Skeet, whose answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/887448/1220971) it's based on.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = char.MinValue; i <= char.MaxValue; i++) {
    char c = Convert.ToChar(i);
    if (!char.IsSymbol(c)) {
        //kung-fu!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var c = System.Char.MinValue; c != char.MaxValue; ++c)
    DoSomething(c);
DoSomething(char.MaxValue);
```