# Detect non-displayable characters in string C#

Tags: c#, unicode, visual-studio-2019

Hopefully someone can help me with this, because I haven't found any solution online so far.

I am processing strings with special characters and I want to detect if any character in a string can't be displayed properly by for instance a webbrowser or even Visual Studio itself. The following string shows such characters. This comes from the Text vizualizer in VS2019:

```
TargetsforReduceCO
```

I've checked similar questions, but the answers were mostly limited to checking if the character code exceeds 255. However, there are lots of characters that can still be displayed, like Greek and Cyrillic symbols.

I also found [this](https://www.utf8icons.com/) website that has an overview of all Unicode characters and show how they are displayed in the browser, but there doesn't seem to be any logic in which characters can't be displayed and their character code.

I can imagine that VS doesn't know which characters can't be displayed in various browsers, but I'm hoping that there is at least a way of checking if VS can display them.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit:**

Right now I'm using

```
input.Any(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) && c > 255);
```

Because the input shouldn't normally contain other symbols than what you can usually find in a text, but I'm sure it will be triggered on symbols that can actually be displayed by VS or a webbrowser.

Comment: The questions you mention aren't related - 255 is the limit for single-byte codepages, not Unicode or UTF8. Are you sure you aren't reading those characters using the wrong codepage? Where did that string come from? It looks like an entire word was lost in that string.

Comment: You will have to be very clear as to what you mean by "cannot be displayed". The example you showed has characters that are in the private-use area, but do you also want to count characters that are not supported by any of the fonts installed in the OS, or characters that have 0 width (e.g. RTL mark, ZWJ)? IMO, these are all reasonable definitions of "cannot be displayed".

Comment: With cannot be displayed I mean that they are shown as a box/rectangle with a questionmark in it.
The string comes from some open source software that tries to convert custom designed fonts into a string. It doesn't always work because designers are very creative :). In those cases it will convert it into strange characters.

Comment: Note: the box with number is a sort of displayed character, and it is handled by font. And looking characters handled by fonts is very complex (various table, and shaper may combine characters into one glyph. In short: it is nearly impossible, if you are not willing to talk with the display engine (and so you know the font installed). But instead of removing it, why do you have such characters? Maybe you should start from there

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: I am willing to do anything possible, including talking to the display engine if I know how :).
Right now, removing these characters is outside of my scope. I'm just handling what others give me. I want to warn them that they insert strings with these characters, so they can remove them.

Comment: If other people give you such data, you should check and understand the meaning. Removing data is dangerous: you may merge words that should not be merged, or change meaning (and creating very offensive words). Windows? Check Uniscribe or DirectWrite. Note: on a different machine you get different results. (If you install Noto fonts, you may get much less such cases, but if input text were broken, you still have broken text)

Comment: This is font-dependent, so unless you can specify which font to use you can't check it.

Comment: I can actually read all of those characters, courtesy of the Unicode fallback font -- they're boxes with hex codes to me, not question marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `char` has a number of static member methods like `IsPunctuation()` that should help you "categorize" character by character.  See example on this page [System.Char reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=net-5.0). Each of those methods' documentation explains what characters it applies to. As commenters have mentioned, your "displayable" criterion is more a font-presentation problem than a character value problem but you'll be able to narrow down what your system can work with using these methods.  Look out for other methods like `GetUnicodeCategory()`.

It may be that something as simple as `!char.IsControl(c)` will do the trick.

See similar Q&A here [C# Printable Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887377/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-printable-characters-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for the insights! I checked the different categories of GetUnicodeCategory and It's still possible that some categories contain characters that certain browsers can't show. However, it at least makes sense to check for the PrivateUse category, which will always be custom symbols I guess and is the only category I found in all my examples. So, not 100% of what I wanted, but I guess the best option for now.